# Makeup showing very weak and washed out

Tags: lighting, studio-lighting

I did my first makeup oriented photo shoot last night and results were a surprise, and not in a good way!

I wanted under the eyes to start from black and gradually go to pink. The makeup artist did that and it looked the way we wanted it to when looking at model's face, but when I was taking the picture it was barely even showing and it was maybe four times lighter. What was happening that I couldn't figure it out? The flash wasn't too powerful because model's face was properly exposed or even a bit under exposed, and as for location of light I was using a beauty dish with a grid on it, kind of straight towards the model face similar to a clamshell position.

So what was wrong? Makeup, lighting, or both?

Comment: Could you post an example?

Comment: will try, later tonight when I get home.

Comment: what type of camera do you use? digital/analog? exact model?

Comment: Why would exact model of camera matter?

Comment: Yeap, we need an image. The make up can look diferent (lighter) due overexposure, reflections, white balance, etc. But also sometimes you need to make stronger make up for photos using flash.

Comment: Ok currently at work...will upload an image later tonight prob around midnight

Comment: Lots of variables to consider here.. How are you metering? Spot off the face or Make up area? or are you using an incident light meter? Also, what is your key light, Broadside? Narrow side? or short lighting? how many stops under is the beauty dish? is it causing an over exposed image from the top of the face? and are you metering just below the chin? Also, is the white balance set correctly? An example will really help..

Comment: \*ping\* Can you upload example images of this problem?

Comment: Any chance of that example?

Comment: I have the finished image. Funny thing is my ID for this page is set on work computer machine, when I go home I have the photo, when I go to work I have the ID to login! not both together lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Could it be due to Metamerism?**

Metamerism is a phonomenon that affects the rendering of some colours under certain circumstances. It is possible that the make-up that was used was not appropriate for photographic sessions.

The effect can be observed when trying to photograph some kind of flowers such as the Morning Glory that looks pink but photographs bluish (or the other way around - I get confused.)

The elderly Macbeth™ "Color Check-r" had a square dedicated to demonstrating this as well as the GATF (Graphic Arts Technical Foundation) Light Indicator strips.